# slick insert or update by custom field

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to update line by custom field or insert new line if line does not exists into table. Can I do it by one query with slick 3.0 ?

Done it by 2 queries like this.

```
 Await.result(db.run(myQ.filter(_.firstUserId === my.firstUserId).result), Duration.Inf).headOption match {
      case Some(l) => update(myQ.update(l.updateStatus(my.status)))
      case None => Await.result(db.run(myQ += my), Duration.Inf)
    }
```

BR!

Answer (score -1):

Use the function `insertOrUpdate` in Slick 3.0, see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleInsertActionComposer

Comment: Yep, but for insertOrUpdate i should now id. In the my case I do not know id. I should use some custom field for updating.